# ReactJS: How to deploy on local server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, deployment, localhost

I have a web app developed with a NodeJS + Express + GraphQL + MongoDB back-end and a ReactJS + Apollo front-end. I would like to deploy this application *locally*. Is that even possible?

I have come across dozens of "how to deploy to Heroku," "how to deploy to Digital Ocean", "how to deploy to Github", etc. But none that explains how to deploy locally.

Right now, I run: `nodemon server` for the back-end, and `npm start` for the front-end. I see the application running on `http://localhost:3000/` (I use cors to connect the front end with the server running on port 3001).

I would like to just go to `http://localhost:3000/` and see the app without having to execute the commands `npm start` and `nodemon server`. Is this possible? If so, how do I do that?

To my knowledge, our local server is not a WAMP server (our OS is Windows though). The IT department told me that it is a

> [...] plain, regular old server. The address is localhost running on
>   port 3000. You can open up another port on 3001 if you need it. Just
>   drop your stuff on the C: drive and you should be good to go. I've
>   never heard of Node or React so I can't help if you have questions.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**

There seems to be a bit of confusion surrounding what I am looking for. I am trying to deploy this locally.

Let's say, on your local computer (your laptop at home) you go to localhost:3000 on your favorite browser. Unless you are serving something to localhost in that moment nothing is going to show up, it will say "refused to connect" or something. What I want is to be able to open any machine on the network whenever I go to localhost:3000 and my react site appears and functions...does that make more sense?

I don't want this is development mode. I want a build of this project on localhost...I'm starting to think this isn't possible.

Comment: You can just try to add `npm start` and `nodemon server` to your startup tasks, and then hide the terminal. This way your server will be always running (unless errors are thrown, then it will crash)

Comment: I thought about doing that...but I'm not so sure IT will be okay with it always running... :(

Comment: I don't understand it then. What is your desired result?

Comment: I want to build my react app...then "deploy" it locally. So when I go to localhost 3000 it just appears without ever having execute npm start and nodemon server

Comment: What npm command does, is running a local react server. You cannot access a server, if one is not running.

Comment: I guess you can use React in your app by importing it in a static, local html file, check here: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html . But it won't be available on localhost:3000.

Comment: I'll look into this...but I'm not really sure this is going to work. I have a full application. With routes, views, multiple components and the backend. My hesitation is the load time. How long would it take this method to load all of that? I really do appreciate you taking the time to help @SlawomirWozniak!

Comment: I think it would be less efficient, because the React scripts would need to be loaded at every access to the html file. Personally I also wouldn't choose this option because it doesn't look good in code.

Comment: @SlawomirWozniak After looking into it a little I agree with you. Hmm...stumped. I should have figured this out long before I developed the entire application. oops :) I'll end our back and forth here bc I don't want to make the comments on here too long. Thank you so much anyway for your help, input, and time really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey @SlawomirWozniak if you type your original comment as an answer I can give you the bounty :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem you can create a startup script, which executes `npm start` and `nodemon server`. Then make sure to keep it hidden, so that your server will be always running. Keep in mind though, that any errors thrown will stop your server and unless you configure it, the server won't reload by itself.

Comment: just add a cron job 
https://askubuntu.com/a/816

Answer (score 5):

As i understood, you want to deploy it on a **local server**, not **locally** on your developing device.

> I thought about doing that...but I'm not so sure IT will be okay with it always running... :(

How can you use a server if its not running? Just like WAMP (which runs apache), or whatever you got rolling there, it must be running. So, just make it a background process like [slawomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9941439/slawomir-wozniak) suggested.

PS I dont think you understand node server properly though.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34282424/7399894) to understand why node server needs reloading. After that you need to understand that no hot reload tool is perfect, and you gonna need to restart your server from time to time.

PPS I dont know what this means

> [...] plain, regular old server. The address is localhost running on port 3000.

if there is a server running on 3000, youll need to change port for your server to smth else (most common is 9000)

Comment: I do understand "node server properly". I'm not an idiot. I know why it "needs reloading". The problem is that I do not want to have to run a command to start the node process. Just as if you would deploy it to heroku you can just go to your site and it's there working, you don't need to run `nodemon server`. I don't think heroku is running `nodemon server` everyday for every website they have up...does that make sense

Comment: I too don't know what "plain regular old server" means. But that's all the info the IT department is giving me...that's all I have to work with...

Comment: wow, i didnt say youre an idiot, we all lack of knowledge somewhere, especially me.
if you have a running local server that doesnt turn off, than starting the node server once is enough.
If your local server does turn off or restart, youll need either to run nodemon everytime that happens, or setup up a script that will run it in boot time (in windows you can add it to startup tasks as suggested by slawomir)
heroku runs it during vm boot
*plain regular old server* is irrelevant for you, you only need to check which ports are occupied on that server

Comment: oh no I wasn't saying you were calling me an idiot...sorry I'm a little snippy this morning I apologize. But yes this was my initial thought but IT gave me a little push back on the concept of it "always running". Idk. They're not being very helpful...I think they're just going to have to deal :)

Comment: alright...thank you for your time!  Is it possible to give 50+ bounty to both you and slawomir?

Comment: i really dunno :D 

But since slawomir gave you the answer you need, i think he deserves the bounty (i think he will need to re-type it as an answer first, dont think you give bounty to comment)

Comment: I just offered it to him but if he doesn't post the answer the bounty is your my friend :) Thanks a bunch

Comment: np. I just seen your updated question, though. Now im confused in what your IT guy has to do with it, cause if its your PC/laptop, you can set it up as you like (as long as you have admin or necessary privileges on it), it will run continuously on your device.

Comment: oh I was using "my computer" as an example. Sorry about that...tried to make it less confusing but did the opposite :) oops

Answer (score 1):

I would try following:

1. build your app with the production environment variables set
2. get all files from dist folder and deploy them in your server
3. now access your app using localhost/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) which creates a socks tunnel to your localhost, effectivelly deploying from localhost, as I understand it, allowing you to access your localhost through a url like `ldiuhv093.ngrok.io`, or even a custom subdomain if you pay for a subscription fee.

If I have this wrong, someone please tell me!

Comment: I have a web app that acts as an FTP client. It is meant for accessing local FTP servers. and it works like a charm in the local environment. Hosting the web app in Heroku doesn't work as the FTP server is local. Does ngrok solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Note: Assuming that the FTP server and PC (which accesses the website) are always on the same network. I do not want my local FTP server to expose.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem first of need to create a batch file with `.bat or .cmd` extension and under that file add the following 2 command

`nodemon server` 
`npm start`

Then follows the following steps to add it as a startup script for windows OS.

1. Create a shortcut to the batch file.
2. Once the shortcut has been created, right-click the file and select
   Cut.
3. Press the Start button and type Run and press enter.
4. In the Run window, type shell:startup to open the Startup folder.
5. Once the Startup folder has been opened, click the Home tab at the
   top of the folder and select Paste to paste the shortcut into the
   folder.

Above steps are for example to create a batch file and add it as a startup script for Windows 8 and 10 users.
For better clarity or reference follows the following link.[reference-link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000322.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There's no option to reload the server while keeping it running. You could, technically, have your 'main' file monitor another file for changes. This would be the file where you actually keep your sever program. Then, on changes, you discard your current logic and start executing that. That said, doing it that way would be very fragile and a very round-about way to do it. It also wouldn't fix your front-end for which you'd need a similar solution.

Instead, you could hook into your favorite editor's save event, and run those two console commands, so that every time you save, the server is automatically brought up. (Make sure to also clean up existing servers)

- [Run on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) for VSCode
- [save-commands](https://atom.io/packages/save-commands) for Atom

Answer (score 0):

I know this post has been two years. But, I think the solution to your second desired outcome is to use concurrency. https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently.
This will allow you to do one NPM START to start two all three processes.

and to your first question, I think the solution is to add Electron to your app so you can package it to an executable application. When you start the app, your express server will start running in the background.

Most people probably don't understand why there is a need for this. Running on local server (computer) allows access to local file system and can even run SQL queries inside the proxy which would require IT involvement if hosted on outside server.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understand, that you want to deploy your app on local server that means you want to deploy it on the network that you are connected to.

Check ip from the command prompt
To deploy it locally,
Run: HOST=ip npm run start

It will get deploy on your local server. And everyone connected to the server can access the url

If this worked for you, kindly upvote

Answer (score 0):

read this post: https://www.upbeatcode.com/react/how-to-run-react-js-build-locally/

1. in your react app, run `npm run build`, it'll build to `.\build` folder
2. `npm install -g serve`
3. `cmd cd` to the build folder
4. `serve build`

change port number: `serve -l port`, help use `serve --help`.

Answer (score -3):

You need to do `npm start` There may be other ways of starting it but, all will result in the same. You can read this article on Freecodecamp on deploying on DigitalOcean. You can manipulate it to your localhost. Shouldn't be too different.[FCC Tut on Deploying](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/i-built-this-now-what-how-to-deploy-a-react-app-on-a-digitalocean-droplet-662de0fe3f48)

Comment: I don't want to deploy on DigitalOcean. I want to keep it local....`npm start` is merely for the front-end in development mode. Not for production...

Comment: I know. Read my answer. I said to manipulate the tutorial to your case. If you want, I can help.